# How to create a jar with external libraries included from the command line?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I know this option from eclipse, but how can I do it from the command line?

When compiling the java application, those jar files are in different paths:

First in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib` (I'm using CMake but that should not matter for the question)

Second in `/usr/share/java`.

Comment: The best answer is usually "use Maven or Gradle".

Comment: There is no simple command for that?

Comment: If you don’t use gradle nor maven, you are probably inside an IDE.  That IDE probably can do it for you.

Comment: I want to do it with a command in the command line(more specific, with add_custom_command)